# "N+1 selects problem" with JpaRepository method despite using @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I encountered "N+1 selects problem" despite using @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) in a very complex software, for simplicity I created an example published on GitHub. The problem is that I can’t use the JOIN mode to acquire data, the behavior always generates the “N+1 selects problem”. I've a very large dataset in the main table, in my case N is about 10/15k, executing JOIN is mandatory.

Here's the code [( full and executable on GitHub )](https://github.com/stefanoriffaldi/stack-samples/tree/main/spring-data-jpa-fetch-mode)

```
public class Student {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
//    @ManyToOne
//    @JoinColumn(name = "university_id")
//    private University university;
}

public class University {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany/*(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)*/
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
}

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {
}

public interface UniversityRepository extends JpaRepository<University, String> {
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootTestClass.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Log4j2
public class FetchTypeTest {
    @Autowired
    private UniversityRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void findAll() {
        List<University> universityList = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 100)).getContent();
        for (University university : universityList) {
            log.info("{} [{}]", university.getName(), university.getAddress());
            for (Student student : university.getStudents()) {
                log.info("{}, {}", student.getLastName(), student.getFirstName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expectation is to see 1 and only 1 query that (left outer) join University and Student, but executing the test log show 3 select: 1 on University, 2 on Student (there are 2 universities and 5 student for each university) despite FetchMode.JOIN usage. I tried every passible combination of FetchMode / FetchType, but nothin works

Dependencies:

- Java 8
- spring-boot:1.5.8
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.8
- spring-data-jpa:1.11.18
- hibernate-core:5.0.12
- hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindAll*` methods of `spring-data-jpa` implemented Queries that ignore fetch modes. When you write a query, you are telling what is joined and what is not joined.

Fetch mode is only taken into account when entity is loaded with methods like `findById` or when navigating through some other entity graph and loading its associations.

This is the [refer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html)

> The fetch strategy defined in the mapping document affects:
>
> retrieval via get() or load()
>
> retrieval that happens implicitly when an association is navigated
>
> Criteria queries
>
> HQL queries if subselect fetching is used.

You can define a method like this

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM University u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.students s order by u.name")
  Page<Region> findAllUniversitiesWithPagination(Pageable pageable);
```

But note that this method is paginating in memory

```
HHH90003004: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory
```

Following this [post](https://vladmihalcea.com/join-fetch-pagination-spring/) to solve that problem.

Comment: thanks, have you a docs ref about "Fetch mode is only taken into account when entity is loaded with methods like findById" and "" ? it would be very usefull. !

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi yeah I added it into the answer

Comment: your tip give me the right path, but spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch property seems not working ...

Comment: Hi @StefanoRiffaldi I cannot answer your question, following this [repo](https://github.com/AnghelLeonard/Hibernate-SpringBoot/tree/master/HibernateSpringBootHHH000104) it's successful to reproduce the issue. Can u mark the answer as correct?