# Hibernates OneToMany with Fetch Eager and Fetch Join not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I expect this code will be using join instead of select query, but it uses select. 
A user has one or many posts and a post belongs to one user only. 
In the `User` entity, I set `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` and `FetchMode.JOIN` on the `posts` association.

did I do or misunderstand something wrong here?

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    List<Post> posts;

}
```

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    String content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    User user;

}
```

This is the log

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.name from users u1_0
Hibernate: select p1_0.user_id,p1_0.p_id,p1_0.content from post p1_0 where p1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select p1_0.user_id,p1_0.p_id,p1_0.content from post p1_0 where p1_0.user_id=?
Hibernate: select p1_0.user_id,p1_0.p_id,p1_0.content from post p1_0 where p1_0.user_id=?
```

This data I get when use `userRepo.findAll()`

```json
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Jose",
         "posts":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "content":"Java and PHP"
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "content":"Deep learning"
            },
            {
               "id":4,
               "content":"C#"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"William",
         "posts":[
            {
               "id":2,
               "content":"Moon and Sun"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"Pito",
         "posts":[
            {
               "id":5,
               "content":"Water and Tree"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Is this answer your question [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77817535/6633045)?